# Call controller method with List<MyItem> parameter via ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this class in my c# code:

```
public class MyItem
    {
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public int ddlId { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my Js/Ajax code:

```
var array = new Array();
grid.forEachRow(function (id) {
        var object = {
            LocationId: id,
            Value: someValue,
            ddlId: otherValue
        };
        array.push(object);
    });

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/MyController/SaveTheList",
    data: { myList: array },
    success:function() { }
 });
```

And here is the method in the controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SaveTheList(List<MyItem> myList)
 { }
```

The method gets hit, and myList has the exact length, but all the values in the objects are 0.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you inspect with fiddler (or similar) what exactly data is being sent to in your AJAX request in POST body,

Something tells me that

> data: { myList: array }

will look something like "Object#1,Object#2,Object#3"
because of how jQuery will try to serialize your array of objects

as a solution try passing data on youj jQuery request as JSON string, than MVC binder should be able to bind data;

Answer (score 1):

Before this:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/MyController/SaveTheList",
    data: { myList: array },
    success:function() { }
 });
```

use this:

```js
$.ajaxSetup({ traditional:true });
```

I had the same problem and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could send it as `JSON` request and also you should `stringify` your data:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/MyController/SaveTheList",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ myList: array }),
    success: function (result) {

    }
});
```